# Anyone can integrate $e^{-\frac{x^2}{3}}$ by hands?

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics

I just used wolfram integral calculator and the result is weird, there is something called error function.

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}{3}}\,\mathrm dx
$$
Hint says that change of variable might be helpful, but can't think of what to change and substitute.

Anyone can do this by hands?

Comment: Welcome to mathSE! I'm sorry but your integral don't have a closed form.

Comment: You sure you didn't misread the question?

Comment: I did not misread it. this is right integral that I was asked to integrate by hands for the quizz

Comment: Actually, there is a boundary, negative infinity to infinity, does that help?

Comment: do you want to find a closed form of the primitive function or integrate over $\mathbb{R}$? because in the latter case it's a well-known result, especially since I see you've put 'statistics' tag on it

Comment: The reason why I put statistic tag is that the result of this integral is widely used in the field of statistic, that's what my professor said.

Comment: Are you sure about the $3$ in the denominator ?

Comment: yes I am sure, and I found out that integration of e^(-x^2/2) over the same boundary is square root of 2pi, would that be helpful?

Comment: See [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Comment: So you want $u$ such that $\frac{u^2}{2}=\frac{x^2}{3}.$ It's just a constant of proportionality, easiest substitution in the book.

Answer (score 7):

Let $$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{3}\right)dx$$.

$$I^2=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{3}\right)dx\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{3}\right)dy$$

$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2+y^2}{3}\right)dxdy$$
$$=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{3}\right)rdrd\theta$$
$$=2\pi\frac{3}{2}\int_0^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{3}\right)d\left(\frac{r^2}{3}\right)$$
$$=3\pi$$

$$I=\sqrt{3\pi}$$

Comment: Basically re-deriving the constant factor in the standard normal distribution function. Or you can simply cite the well-known result as mm-aops did and save three or four lines of calculations.

Answer (score 2):

hint: what's the density of a standard (normal) distribution? take $y := cx$ with appropriately chosen $c$ (and use the fact that integral of a density is $1$)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem assumes that you already know that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx = \sqrt{\pi}$$
(or possibly a small variation of this) and your mission is to evaluate
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/3}dx$$
by using a substitution to express a definite integral involving $e^{-x^2/3}$ into one involving $e^{-x^2}$.  Let's try.

First, note that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/3}dx = 2\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^b e^{-x^2/3}dx.$$
Thus, we'll focus on
$$\int_0^b e^{-x^2/3}dx.$$
Let us make the substitution $u=x/\sqrt{3}$.  Then $dx=\sqrt{3}du$ so
$$\int_0^b e^{-x^2/3}dx = \int_0^b e^{-(x/\sqrt{3})^2}dx = \sqrt{3}\int_0^{b/\sqrt{3}} e^{-u^2} du.$$
Taking a limit as $b\rightarrow\infty$, we get
$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2/3}dx = \sqrt{3}\int_0^{\infty} e^{-u^2} du = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}\sqrt{\pi}.$$
The answer to your integral is twice this.

A few comments

- This is one of the first examples that most people see of a definite integral that can be computed in closed form without ever finding a closed form expression for the corresponding indefinite integral.
- The fact that
  $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx = \sqrt{\pi}$$
  can be proved directly using the technique shown in Kyson's answer.
- An alternative formulation of the integral (equivalent by the same substitution technique is
  $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2}dx = 1.$$
- The previous integral is known as the Gaussian normal and is of tremendous importance in statistics.